# How StandardScaler does not disrupt data integrity?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Since by using sklearns's StandardScaler the initial data are normalized, isn't that problematic that the initial data are not the same anymore?

Example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np


data = np.array([[1,1],[2,0]])
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(data)

print(data)
[[1 1]
[2 0]]

print(scaled_data)
[[-1.  1.]
 [ 1. -1.]]
```

As you can see the data are not the same due to normalization. How that change is not affecting the results in future processing since the data are different and in what scenario is suitable to perform normalization (basically we do that for data which have negative values but I mean in what processes is it appropriate)?

Comment: It depends on what you are doing. In a regression problem, you may be in the need of scale your output back to its native space. The transformation IS affecting the processing: it is making the computation numerically more stable.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go to official docs for the function:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html

From that, we can see this formula:
The standard score of a sample x is calculated as:

z = (x - u) / s
Here u - mean & s - standard deviation

[image]

As per Normal distribution theorem, we can represent any data using above formula & distribution.

Geometrically, we are subtracting all the values of a field/column with a same value & dividing with the another same value.

We are just rescaling the data.So, data integrity will not be lost

Answer (score 0):

Another point to keep in mind is that the defaults for the StandardScaler class in sklearn do **not** modify the data in-place by default:

"**copy : boolean, optional, default True**
If False, try to avoid a copy and do inplace scaling instead. This is not guaranteed to always work inplace; e.g. if the data is not a NumPy array or scipy.sparse CSR matrix, a copy may still be returned."

So above, since you've assigned the results to the *scaled_data* name, the object that is referenced by *data* is unchanged as long as you don't change the copy=True default parameter in StandardScaler.